# Mapstruct maven dependency download not working in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, maven, spring-tool-suite, mapstruct

STS is showing the message "Updating Maven Project: (75%)" at the bottom right corner and never ends that for hours (literally).

It happens when I add mapstruct to pom.xml (as in the first pom.xml below).

If I remove mapstruct lines from pom.xml (as in the second pom.xml below) the maven update completes just fine.

But I need to use mapstruct.

Tried with Mapstruct 1.5.1.Final and 1.5.2.Final. Same issue on both.

## With mapstruct (maven update not working)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <description>aaaaaaaaa</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>1.8</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- other annotation processors -->
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
        
    </build>

</project>
```

## Without mapstruct (maven update working fine)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <description>aaaaaaaaa</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
                
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
        
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Plain command build works?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm using maven that comes built in STS. So running mvn command in command prompt doesn't work. I might install maven outside STS to give a try.

Comment: So first try to install MVN and try your build on plain command line...if that works... than into STS...

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me from STS.

Maybe your local maven repo is damaged. Try deleting folder `1.5.2.Final` from `$USER/.m2/repository/org/mapstruct/mapstruct/1.5.2.Final` or from wherever your repo is.

Comment: I deleted the whole .m2 folder before and downloaded all dependencies from scratch. Same result.

Comment: If you go to https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mapstruct/mapstruct/1.5.2.Final/ and download the .jar and the .pom to $USER/.m2/repository/org/mapstruct/mapstruct/1.5.2.Final you should be able to work.

Comment: The issue is in mapstruct-processor, not in mapstruct. The mapstruct code in the <dependency> section of pom.xml is working fine. The problem is when I add the mapstruct-processor section in the <build> part of pom.xml.

Comment: So I followed your suggestion and downloaded from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-processor/1.5.2.Final/ the following files: mapstruct-processor-1.5.2.Final.jar, mapstruct-processor-1.5.2.Final.jar.sha1, mapstruct-processor-1.5.2.Final.pom, mapstruct-processor-1.5.2.Final.pom.sha1 and copied them directly to local \.m2\repository\org\mapstruct\mapstruct-processor\1.5.2.Final. I left the  _remote.respositories file that was in that folder already. The problem continued. Should I add the other files available in the maven remote repo or just those four are enough?

Comment: You also need mapstruct, not just mapstruct-processor. Having the jars in your rep should allow you to work but will still indicate problems collecting the dependency (75% in STS)

Comment: BTW what does your _remote.respositories file contain. I suspect that STS is struggling to reach a specific repo. Also, do you have a mvnw.bat/cmd in the root of your project?

Comment: Sure. I do have mapstruct. It's in the .m2 repo and running well. Just said that the problem (75% in STS) happens when I add the mapstruct-processor xml section to pom.xml

Comment: Here is the content of \.m2\repository\org\mapstruct\mapstruct-processor\1.5.2.Final\ _remote.repositories:
#NOTE: This is a Maven Resolver internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Fri Jan 27 13:28:24 BRT 2023
mapstruct-processor-1.5.2.Final.jar>central=
mapstruct-processor-1.5.2.Final.pom>central=

Comment: About your comment "Having the jars in your rep should allow you to work but will still indicate problems collecting the dependency (75% in STS) ". That is not what I'm experiencing. STS is pretty blocked trying to do that update.

Comment: If you restart STS and try and do a Run As > Maven test, does it compile?

Comment: If I close STS and open it again it will directly get to the "Updating Maven Project: (75%)" message. Then if I go to Run As > Maven Test, it will show this message in the Progress window: "Launching Executing test in C.... (Blocked: The user operation in waiting for "Building" to complete)". So it is waiting for the 75% to complete to then run maven test.

Comment: I created a new application in a new STS workspace. Then copied the exact content of this pom.xml file and it worked. Looks like the original application has something else conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add a mapstruct processor.

This should help you:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Did you see the first block of code that I posted? Processor that you suggested is already there.

Comment: Damn, now I see. Sorry for misguiding.

Comment: btw, this part of my code that has the processor is the exact one that is blocking maven update. If I remove that but leave the other parts that make reference to mapstruct the maven update works fine.

Comment: I know it could be an issue due to Lombok, but I don't see it in your pom. Have you tried to mnv package + Reload Maven Project and then Invalidate Caches?

Comment: Right, I'm not using lombok. As for the mvn, I'm using the maven that comes bundled in STS. So executing maven from STS, not command line. Not sure I can do mvn package command with that. Think it would be needed an external maven installation right? Also... how to invalidate caches?

Comment: From the main menu, select File | Invalidate Caches.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html

Comment: I'm using Spring Tool Suite.